# Send arguments to a Job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I have a docker Image that basically runs a one time script. That scripts takes 3 arguments. My docker file is

```
FROM <some image>

ARG URL
ARG USER
ARG PASSWORD

RUN apt update && apt install curl -y

COPY register.sh .
RUN chmod u+x register.sh

CMD ["sh", "-c", "./register.sh $URL $USER $PASSWORD"]
```

When I spin up the contianer using `docker run -e URL=someUrl -e USER=someUser -e PASSWORD=somePassword -itd <IMAGE_ID>` it works perfectly fine.

Now I want to deploy this as a job.

My basic Job looks like:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: register
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: register
        image: registeration:1.0
        args: ["someUrl", "someUser", "somePassword"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

But this the pod errors out on

```
Error: failed to start container "register": Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"someUrl\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Looks like it is taking my args as commands and trying to execute them. Is that correct ? What can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dockerfile as you've written it, two things happen:

1. The URL, username, and password are fixed in the image.  Anyone who can get the image can run `docker history` and see them in plain text.
2. The container startup doesn't take any arguments; it just runs the single command with its fixed set of arguments.

Especially since you're planning to pass these arguments in at execution time, I wouldn't bother trying to include them in the image.  I'd reduce the Dockerfile to:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      curl
COPY register.sh /usr/bin
RUN chmod u+x /usr/bin/register.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["register.sh"]
```

When you launch it, the Kubernetes `args:` get passed as command-line parameters to the entrypoint.  (It is the same thing as the Docker Compose `command:` and the free-form command at the end of a plain `docker run` command.)  Making the script be the container entrypoint will make your Kubernetes YAML work the way you expect.

In general I prefer using CMD to ENTRYPOINT.  (Among other things, it makes it easier to `docker run --rm -it ... /bin/sh` to debug your image build.)  If you do that, then the Kubernetes `args:` need to include the name of the script it's running:

```
args: ["./register.sh", "someUrl", "someUser", "somePassword"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
args: ["sh", "-c", "./register.sh someUrl someUser somePassword"]
```

Comment: Edited my answer